# Why have I need kicked several times and banned in chat for 24 hours?

Tags: discussion, chat

I had a - what I think - respectful discussion about a problem in the Python language in the Python chat room. I have been told that I have not created an accurate code example to reproduce a problem I was asking about, and kicked three times. In addition, I have been banned from chat for 24 hours.

I do not see any violation against the rules in that room. I always stayed polite and NEVER insulted someone or did something I would consider rude.

What can I do to claim my right? Why have I been kicked? Is there something I can do against this seemingly random and wrong behavior?

Comment: I can't speak for any of the room owners, but as someone who was in the room at the time. My impression is that you were kicked because you were refusing to listen to any of the advice you were given, or to provide an MCVE, as was requested from you many times.

Comment: For context, the relevant conversation starts here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32209137#32209137 . In addition to the kick, you are currently suspended by a moderator from chat for a day.

Comment: I do not think that 'refusing to listen' is in itself a violation against the room rules. I still stayed nice. Since when is a rule to 'listen to advice'? I DO listen to the advice, anyway...

Comment: @Brad: When did I explicitly violated the chat rules. Please point to that exact point in the discussion. Thank you!

Comment: You _don't_ have to listen to advice, or provide a MCVE. You're free to go and solve your problem yourself. But you can't repeatedly ignore the advice, refuse to provide a MCVE and then hassle people to help you anyway.

Comment: I see. So you say, that when I repeat the same thing over and over, this counts as being rude?

Comment: @Alex Yes. I would consider it rude. If you ask a question, it's rude to ignore the answers you are given and continue to ask the same question.

Comment: sigh. I see a double reversal coming. What were you even thinking @Alex? This has been explained to you multiple times while you were in the room. Thats so disappointing for a high rep user.

Comment: I genuinely don't see how you can be construed as NOT rude. Rude != insulting. Rude is also... well... rude. I genuinely understand your current predicament @Alex. Some of these DB issues are real tough to troubleshoot. The problem that you don't seem to grasp is that it's IMPOSSIBLE (not hard, IMPOSSIBLE) to provide better help without seeing what you're doing. Short of an MCVE, this isn't something that can be done. If you don't wanna hear that and just keep on hammering you can't do an MCVE and need help... yeah, I kinda understand the kick(s)

Comment: @Morgan: Thank you for this answer! My rudeness will not happen again. I promise!!

Comment: @Alex it's more "rude" in the sense that you're requesting help from others, but then you don't accept help, unless it's given the way YOU want. Everyone suggesting things here are volunteers, you aren't entitled to getting your issues fixed. Stack may just not be the site for the type of issue you're encountering right now, is all. (good luck with it... hunting these down can be a pain :( )

Comment: I did not want my issue fixed. This is not what I wanted. How could someone fix an issue without sufficient information about it? No example code? No way you can solve the problem! The only thing I was asking, I am sorry to repeat myself, for some guidance, for some general ideas where I might look myself. That is all. Like, "hey, sqlite3 does not well with different processes". Perfect! That is what I was looking for! Maybe this is the solution to my problem, maybe it is not. But it is something I can dig deeper into, to debug myself, to try something else. I never asked for a full solution..

Comment: @Alex but there was a point where you were told pretty much exactly that.... you then came back to continue.... it was pointed out to you "SQLite is explicitly stated to not be good (at least by default) at concurrent writes. But it is safe about them."  at which point you got another kick, AND came back....

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you're gonna drop into a room, be respectful of the folks there. If you ask a question and they ask for clarification, then provide it - or just go somewhere else.

Once you've been kicked *multiple* times for not listening, you might want to stop and consider perhaps things are not quite going smoothly.

I gave you 24-hours away from chat so you could get over whatever was bothering you and *maybe* find a way to distill that 7000-line monster you're battling down to something the folks you're asking for help could actually help you with. The folks in the room seem to have given you some pretty good advice; I'd listen to it.

Comment: Thank you Shog for helping the Python room with this.  I appreciate it.

Comment: I think I was respectful to the people in that room. I did not insult anyone, as far as I can remember. I did not want to get a straight answer - I wanted just some input on the problems possible cause. To investigate my problem a bit further on my own! Maybe I DID ask my questions not in the right way. Maybe I did not have the patience to try to listen to the advices. For that I am guilty! Maybe I understand the reason for the ban, so I can be part of better discussions in the future. You don't need to lift the ban, I try to follow currently the advice given...

Comment: Just give it 24 hours, and think about how you'd want to talk about such a problem with, say, someone at a user-group meeting, @Alex. Remember, folks are hanging out in chat to socialize with others that share their interests; there are plenty of challenging questions on main.

Comment: Yes I understand. And as I said, I was not looking for an answer (as this is impossible of course). All I wanted was to get some ideas. A suggestion. And I think I got some advice, which I am currently following.

Answer (score 26):

[You were asked to put in the effort to post the relevant code](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32209200#32209200) and responded with a one-line statement that did not contain anything close to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You did not want to put in the effort to create an MCVE with an explanation that was more-or-less "that will take effort on my side."

I kicked you from the room and explained why I did such a thing in at least two [separate](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32209476#32209476) [messages](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32209507#32209507). You are only bringing this to meta because you do not want to accept the explanation you were given (to which you responded with passive aggressiveness in a message that Shog deleted). You came across as feeling entitled to help and not respectful of other peoples' time.

The ban from chat comes from Stack Overflow moderators, but the room kicking came from me. There was nothing "random" about the outcome.

Comment: So the statement is, that one can get kicked even if one does not violate the rules? Is that correct?

Comment: @Alex please take a moment to calm down and come back to this with a clear mind.  I believe that this has already been explained to you.

Comment: @Alex: "*So the statement is, that one can get kicked even if one does not violate the rules? Is that correct?*" This is true, so long as you remove the words "even" and "not" from the statement. Not posting an MCVE when asked, and then continuing to bother people about your problem even after not having provided an MCVE is harassment and general annoyance. I'm pretty sure there are rules against that.